# Why can one be compiled and the other not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This code cannot be compiled because of overflowing:

```
byte number = 1000;
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

But this one gives a value of 1 because of the same reason as of overflowing:

```
byte number = 255;

number += 2;

Console.WriteLine(number);
```

My question is why the first example gives an error and the second one won't?

Comment: The first one is trying to cast an `int` to a `byte` where the value is outside of the size of `byte`.  The second one is just allowing an existing `byte` to have it's value overflow based on the default setup of unchecked overflow.

Comment: *"This code cannot be compiled because of overflowing"* is not really correct. Overflow, by definition, happens at runtime. The compiler is telling you that the constant value cannot be converted to a byte because it's too large.

Comment: FYI, the code samples would be slightly better if we used `257` instead of `1000` (for consistency between the examples)

Answer (score 1):

### [Range of `byte` type is `0 to 255`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types)

In first example, When you are assigning `number = 1000` it is exceeding limit of byte range and gives compile time error.

In second example, you are assigning `number = 255` which is acceptable as `255` is in the byte range. When you are adding `2` to max byte limit i.e `255`, it start from `0` and prints `1` as a result

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't compile because a `byte` can't be set to `1000`.  The second one does compile because a `byte` *can* be set to `255`, and because a value will overflow when performing arithmetic that takes it beyond its bounds.

At no point in the second example do you try to set a `byte` to `1000`.  Each operation present in the second example is valid.  But one operation in the first example is not valid.

Basically, the compiler isn't going to try to calculate your overflow for you.  The runtime will handle an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A `byte` is 8 bits, and a bit can be on our off. Represented mathematically, this is either 0 or 1, off and on respectfully.

So if you put 8 bits in a row, you can start representing numbers in binary :

```
00000000 = 0
00000001 = 1
00000010 = 2
...
11111111 = 255
```

As other people have pointed out, when you add 2 to 255, it overflows and wraps back around :

```
 11111111 (255)
+00000010 (2)
---------------
 00000001 (1)
```

You need a larger primitive, one with at least 10 bits, to represent a number like 1000, and your compiler knows this and is trying to alert you.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy is due to [the rules surrounding C#'s `checked` and `unchecked` contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked-and-unchecked).

- Constant values (those the compiler can determine at compile time, using well-defined rules of the C# specification) default to `checked`. Attempting to assign a value out of range for a numeric type (in your case, assigning `1000` to a `byte`, which has the range `[0,255]`) will result in a compile time error. You can surpress this by wrapping the expression in an `unchecked` context.

  ```
  byte number = unchecked((byte) 1000);
  Console.WriteLine(number);
  ```

  results in `232`.
- Non-constant values - i.e., those calculated at runtime - default to `unchecked`. This allows overflow / underflow to occur. [This blog post explains the rationale for choosing `unchecked` as the default.](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/09/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-one/) You can choose to make an expression or block `checked`, incurring a slight runtime performance penalty to have the runtime throw an exception if overflow / underflow occurs.

  ```
  checked {
      byte number = 255;

      number += 2;

      Console.WriteLine(number);
  }
  ```

  results in [`System.OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception) being thrown on the line with the `+=` operation.

  Or, you can set [the `-checked` compiler flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option) to default to `checked` everywhere except places you mark `unchecked`.